# Dynamic join sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to dynamically join a certain number of tables from a list containing table names, for example if my list contains two elements like this :

```
tables_to_join = ['table1','table2']
```

Then I would like to have a left join between those two tables in the query.

```
table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

And if the table only contains one element, then there will be no need to do a join.

How can I do this with SQLAlchemy please?

I guess I should do something like this :

```
test_query = session.query(my_table).join(tables_to_join)
```

But then how can I manage the case where there will be no need to join (if table_to_join contains only one element) ?

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Can't you just check the length of the `tables_to_join`, and then stick the `.join(tables_to_join)` part in an if loop? Or did I miss something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tables_to_join = [..]

if (len(tables_to_join) > 1):
    query = session.query(eval(tables_to_join[0]))

    for table in tables_to_join[1:]:
        query = query.join(eval(table))
```